# mongodb command "mongosh" giving error even server is running

Tags: mongodb

I am using mondodb "version": "7.0.1"

When I run command `mongosh` it is giving me the bellow error:

`"Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.10.6 MongoServerSelectionError: Server selection timed out after 2000 ms"`

i checked by running command `mongod`, server is running, it is not giving any error.

Can anyone please suggest, how to resolve it.
Thanks

Comment: Does the mongod log show a connection attempt when you run that?

Comment: {"t":{"$date":"2023-09-20T10:23:20.275+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22943,   "ctx":"listener","msg":"Connection accepted","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:62546","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"44dedcda-45c4-431f-a104-149cd882f060"}},"connectionId":1,"connectionCount":1}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-09-20T10:23:20.278+05:30"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":22944,   "ctx":"conn1","msg":"Connection ended","attr":{"remote":"127.0.0.1:62546","uuid":{"uuid":{"$uuid":"44dedcda-45c4-431f-a104-149cd882f060"}},"connectionId":1,"connectionCount":0}}